# Redirect or rewrite any subdomain to www leaving the rest of URL as it is

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, wildcard-subdomain

I have:

```
subdomainaaa.mydomain.com
subdomainaaa.mydomain.com/anything/whatever
subdomainbbb.mydomain.com
subdomainbbb.mydomain.com/anything/whatever
...
...
anysubdomain.mydomain.com ...
```

Practically wild card subdomain.

And I need rewrite rule to make it all:

```
www.mydoamin.com/and_whatever_goes_afterwords
```

Basically, how to redirect zillion subdomains to www, leaving anything that goes after .com/ as it is.

I must do some sort of permanent redirection because I can't lose old links, just to redirect them to new ones with www instead of subdomains

Please, I was looking all over the internet for this, and I get only chunks of regex which I don't know how to put together, and whatever I mix in my .htaccess file - I get server error. Or, I manage to redirect anything just to the homepage www.mydomain.com. I hope I was clear. I am a regex newbie (wannabe), so, please give me the whole chunk to put in .htaccess.
Or, if you think I am doing something wrong - give me suggestion how to accomplish my goal. 
Thanks a lot guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add www and keep same URI
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)[^.]+\.(mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks! But, this needs a little change, please. This makes 'subdomain.mydomain.com/something' become 'www.subdomain.mydomain.com' and **no /something**, so it needs 2 modifications to be - 'www.mydomain.com/something' without .subdomain. in between www and mydomain. Thanks a lot @anubhava!!

Comment: This adds www in front of whole url, I need www to replace subdomain: this makes sub.domain.com became www.sub.domain.com - and I need www.domain.com. I used new browser, cleared cache and all, put it on the top of htaccess. Thanks @anubhava

Comment: Great! Works as I wanted! Thank you very much @anubhava!